# Razor: Creating a view from a nested layout doesn't auto create the sections

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am happily converting to Razor.  However, one irritating thing is that when creating a view, it doesn't add the sections for the selected layout (u2bka masterpages...).

Is this to be amended for RTM or is this it??

Either way, where (or to whom) do I whinge?  It is an absolute pain putting in all the sections.

PS:

u2bka:  Used to be known as.

Comment: Just to verify, are you asking about the views generated by the Add View dialog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Add View dialog for the Razor view engine does not currently support this feature (and probably won't for MVC 3 RTM either). This is because of some fundamental differences between Aspx and Razor. Aspx is declarative which means it's a lot easier to parse in these scenarios. Razor is imperative which means it's a lot more difficult to detect all cases without actually running the page code (which we cannot do because it might have side effects).

But we could consider some heuristics for MVC 4.

Comment: Isn't this something that T4 templates could help with?

Comment: Well, Add View dialog is already using T4 templates. The problem is parsing the files in your project and determining the set of placeholders. Aspx is a lot easier to parse for that info than Razor.

Answer (score 1):

I am not too sure in your case but I would strongly suggest you read Andrew's blog post on Razor's nested layouts. It really explains things.

http://aboutcode.net/2010/11/08/nested-layout-pages-in-razor.html

Comment: thanks for the link. Helped a lot even though I had to do it manually.